# Get image from URL delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, ios7.1

I am trying to load image in my banner as well as URL for that banner and everything is just fine except it apears after a few seconds (10+ sec)

First I was thinking that it may be connection speed but if I hardcoded the line where image needs to apear it apears immediatly.

Here is what I am doing right now.

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:adUrl completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    adJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    adImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", adJson[@"sponsor"][@"sponsor_image"]];
    adUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", adJson[@"sponsor"][@"sponsor_url"]];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

    // Set adImage
    [[self adBanner]setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:adImageURL]]]];

    // Ad TapGuestures to adImage
    UITapGestureRecognizer *adTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(adTapMethod)];
    [[self adBanner]setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [[self adBanner]addGestureRecognizer:adTap];
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

As I said, if I do:

```
[[self adBanner]setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"example.com/img.png"]]]];
```

and put that code out of NSURLSessionDataTask it apears in no second.

What am I doing wrong and how to get image apear as fast as possible?

Comment: make sure you are running the `setImage` on the main queue

Comment: How can I do that I am new in iOS development

Comment: See my answer with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only delays would be from connection & then from the device updating it's display. Remember that the direct call with `dataWithContentsOfURL` forces the main queue to wait on the image before doing anything. If you execute it with a `NSURLSession` it would naturally take a bit longer since it isn't set as a high priority.

You should include `setImage:` as such.

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:adUrl completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    adJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    adImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", adJson[@"sponsor"][@"sponsor_image"]];
    adUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", adJson[@"sponsor"][@"sponsor_url"]];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

    // Set adImage
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[self adBanner] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:adImageURL]]]];

        // Ad TapGuestures to adImage
        UITapGestureRecognizer *adTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(adTapMethod)];
        [[self adBanner] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [[self adBanner] addGestureRecognizer:adTap];
    });
}];
[dataTask resume];
```